# how to produce this particular 3D graph from scalar data in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I am trying to produce this graph using Matlab. The built-in ellipsoid function is confusing. For this problem I have two variables ( width and length ) and a constant height.

to make it very simple I want to show that the width is changing while we approach the tip but height is constant. w,x,h are the variables shown in the graph.

I would really appreciate it if someone can help.

[image: 3D plot]

Comment: Are you trying to reproduce the exact diagram (including arrows) in Matlab - with certain dimensions variable? Or just parts of it? What is the equation that you are plotting? This is not a hard problem, but unless you specify it very clearly you will not like the answer...

Answer (score 3):

The following code gets you a long way, I think. See example output:
[image]

I added enought comments that you should be able to take it from here...

```
% plot ellipsoid in 3D

% height and width of ellipsoid:
e_h = 10;
e_w = 3;

% position where the "quivers" (arrows) go:
q_offset = 2;    % distance from axis
q_scale = 0.5;   % multiplier to give parabola some size
q_spacing = 0.5; % distance between arrows
q_height = 2.5;  % height above XY plane where arrows are drawn
N = 1000;        % number of points for drawing

theta = linspace(0, 2*pi, N); % parameter to help drawing ellipse
zerov = zeros(1, N);          % array of zeros that I will need

% coordinates of main ellipse:
x = e_w * sin(theta);
y = zeros(size(x));
z = e_h * cos(theta);

% plot main ellipse:
figure;
plot3(x, y, z)

% secondary plot
y2 = q_scale*(e_w.^2 - x.^2) + 2; % offset parabola - what your plot looked like...
hold on
plot3(x, y2, zerov+q_height);     % plotting the parabola in the XY plane at height
axis equal % make the plot dimensions isotropic

% add quivers
q_base = -e_w:q_spacing:e_w; % x coordinate; y and z are fixed
q_length = (e_w.^2 - q_base.^2)*q_scale; % length of quiver - just an equation I chose
q0 = zeros(size(q_base)); % another vector I will need multiple times
q1 = ones(size(q_base));  % ditto

% plot the arrows: the "-1" argument means "don't scale"
quiver3(q_base, q0+q_offset, q_height*q1, q0, q_length, q0, -1)
```